# Are there any invalid values from id that use only [a-z0-9]?

Tags: html, dom, xhtml, cross-browser

I'm generating IDs for elements in a page, and would like to make sure I don't stumble across some invalid 'id' value. While the W3 standard seems to say that anything goes, you never know about all browsers, etc, so I'm asking here.

---

I'm talking about `id` as in `<div id='myid' />`.

Comment: Please provide more detail about the doctypes you are targetting.

Comment: html 4, html 5, xhtml 1.0 and 1.1

Answer (score 1):

ID (and NAME) tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

From: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the use of "." and ":" though. It's very likely they'll get interpreted as class and pseudo-class selectors.